# I need a batch script that can delete all folders inside a directory, EXCLUDING certain folders

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need a script that will delete certain folders only. Say a dir contains the folders "Programming, Pictures, Movies, Crap" and lets say I want to keep ONLY the "Programming" and "Crap" folders kind of like adding them as exclusions.

What i DONT want to do is specify the folders to be deleted like:

```
set trashFolder=%userprofile%\Desktop\Test\M…
set trashFolder2=%userprofile%\Desktop\Test\…

rmdir /Q %trashFolder%
rmdir /Q %trashFolder2% <----i dont want this.
```

Lets say I know what folders to KEEP and I dont know whats in that folder so I make a script that specifies what folders to KEEP and delete the rest of the files/folders in that dir.
27 minutes ago - 4 days left to answer.

I pretty much want like a whitelist of folders that I want to keep NOT knowing what else is in that dir. and of course delete everything else except for the folders of that whitelist.

Comment: `27 minutes ago - 4 days left to answer.`? Is this an assignment/exam you're taking here :D

Comment: nah... its a personal experiment with Batch

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways this could be done. Here is one simple method.

```
for /d %%F in (*) do if /i "%%F" neq "Programming" if /i "%%F" neq "Crap" rd /q /s "%%F"
```

If you have a list of folders to keep in a whitelist file named "keep.txt", one folder per line, then you could do something like:

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /ad^|findstr /vxilg:"keep.txt"') do rd /q /s "%%F"
```